# Laravel 5.6. Правило валидации unique. Исключить из проверки поле текущей записи, если оно не изменялось

Tags: php, laravel, валидация

У меня есть класс валидации:

```
class AnalyseRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        'code' => 'required|code_format|unique:analyses',
    }
}
```

В поле code хранится код, который должен быть уникальным. Есть шаблон, где данный код выводится для редактирования. Я редактирую другие поля, code не трогаю. Сохраняю форму. После чего срабатывает данное правило. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно настроить валидатор, чтобы данное правильно срабатывало именно тогда, когда данное значение будет отредактировано на новое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Валидатор [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique) позволяет показывать исключения, в вашем случае это выглядело бы так:

```
public function rules()
{
    'code' => 'required|code_format|unique:analyses,code,' . $id,
}
```

Где `$id` - это PK записи которую редактируете.